# Is temperature equal to the microstates divided by the microstates it gains when you add energy $dE$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

So I am trying to get a more clear picture of what temperature exactly is. Is temperature equal to the microstates divided by the microstates it gains when you add energy $dE$? My reasoning is the following:

$$\frac{dS}{dE}=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{d}{dE}\left(k\ln{\Omega}\right)$$

$$\frac{dS}{dE}=k\frac{d}{dE}\left(\ln{\Omega}\right)=k\frac{d\left(\ln{\Omega}\right)}{d\Omega}\frac{d\Omega}{dE}$$

$$\frac{dS}{dE}=k\frac{1}{\Omega}\frac{d\Omega}{dE}$$

$$\frac{1}{T}=\frac{k}{\Omega}\frac{d\Omega}{dE}$$

$$\frac{\Omega}{kT}=\frac{d\Omega}{dE}$$

So if you isolate $T$ and set $k=1$ then you get:

$$ T=\Omega\left(\frac{d\Omega}{dE}\right)^{-1} $$

This suggests (if I am correct) that temperature is equal to the number of microstates a system has divided by the number of microstates it gains when you add infinitesimal energy $dE$. Does this have any application and is this true in most cases?

Is temperature equal to the microstates divided by the microstates it gains when you add energy $dE$?

Comment: You're describing the formula you got with words in a wrong way. Temperature in your formula is not $\Omega$ divided by $d\Omega$, but $\Omega$ divided by $d\Omega/dE$. You can't replace derivative $d\Omega/dE$ by $d\Omega$ only.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of inverse temperature is
$$
   \frac{1}{k_B T} = \frac{1}{\Omega}
   \left(\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}
$$
By this definition $1/k_B T$ is the *fractional gain of microstates per unit energy*.

Or,
$$
   k_B T = \Omega \Big/
   \left(\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}
$$
which says that *temperature is the number of microstates divided by the density of microstates in energy space (number of microstates per unit energy)*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Pardon me, I think your math is right but your explanation is wrong (or I am misinterpreting it). Since $\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E}$ is the number of microstates a system gains when you add energy $dE$. So this is not the energy density of the microstates.

Comment: @bananenheld In the parenthesis I explain it in words as *number of microstates per unit energy*, but you are correct, I should call it density of microstates in the energy space rather than energy density. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @bananenheld That's not quite right either - $\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E} \mathrm dE$ is the number of microstates you gain when you add energy $\mathrm dE$.